# How to use LPARAM to pass tuples in EnumWindows()

Tags: rust

I want get the main window `HWND` for a process ID, when using C++, call `EnumWindows()` I can pass the PID to a callback function, and get the `HWND`, pack these two variables into a struct, and pass a struct pointer to `LPARAM` of the `EnumWindows` callback.
But in Rust, my code results in a compile error.

I use a tuple in Rust, and try to convert it to pointer and a `LPARAM`, let callback function convert it back to tuples, read PID, write `HWND`.

```rust
use winapi::um::winuser::{EnumWindows, GetWindowThreadProcessId};
use winapi::um::processthreadsapi::OpenProcess;
use winapi::um::handleapi::CloseHandle;
use winapi::um::winnt::PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::{DWORD, LPARAM, TRUE};
use winapi::shared::windef::HWND;

fn get_main_window_handle_from_pid(pid: DWORD) -> Option<HWND> {
    let mut hwnd = None;
    let process_handle = unsafe { OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, TRUE, pid) };
    if !process_handle.is_null() {
        unsafe {
            EnumWindows(Some(enum_windows_callback), LPARAM(&mut (hwnd, pid, process_handle)));
            CloseHandle(process_handle);
        }
    }
    hwnd
}

unsafe extern "system" fn enum_windows_callback(hwnd: HWND, lparam: LPARAM) -> i32 {
    let (hwnd_ptr, pid, process_handle) = &mut *(lparam.0 as *mut (Option<HWND>, DWORD, *mut std::ffi::c_void));
    let mut window_pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &mut window_pid);
    if window_pid == *pid {
        *hwnd_ptr = Some(hwnd);
        return 0;
    }
    1
}
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message (from `cargo build`) to the question.

Comment: You can't use a tuple here, their layout is not specified.